# Recursive line drawing in assembly wrong?

Tags: assembly, recursion, drawing, x86-16

I am trying to draw a line between two points, (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) in assembly and I decided to use an recursive line drawing algorithm instead of Bresenham's. I thought the idea is simple enough and wrote the code, but for some reason it won't work. It does not draw any pixels on screen at all and sometimes it throws illegal instruction exception. Here is the code:

```
line_recursive proc
    pop dx            ; dx = y1
    pop cx            ; cx = x1
    pop bx            ; bx = y0
    pop ax            ; ax = x0

    cmp dx, bx       ; y1==y0
    jne version1
    cmp ax, cx       ; x1==x0
    je  version2
   version1:
    mov si,ax
    add si,cx
    mov di,bx
    add di,dx
    shr si, 1         ; si = (x1+x0)/2 = x
    shr di, 1         ; di = (y1+y0)/2 = y

    push ax
    push cx
    push dx
    mov ah,0Ch  ;print pixel.
    mov al,12
    mov cx,si
    mov dx,di
    int 10h
    pop dx
    pop cx
    pop ax

    ; stack for call for (x0,y0, x,y)
    push ax
    push bx
    push si
    push di
    ; stack for call for (x1,y1, x,y)
    push cx
    push dx
    push si
    push di

    call line_recursive     ; (x1,y1, x,y)
    call line_recursive     ; (x0,y0, x,y)
   version2:
    ret
line_recursive endp
```

I tried to call it in a program after pushing a few numbers to dx, cx, bx and ax. It simply draws nothing, and I see no reason why? I know the pixel print that I use is slow, but that is fine for my study at the moment.
Is my idea of recursion in assembly completely wrong or is there some other reason for this code not working?

Comment: You're aware that `call` puts its return address on the stack, right? You can't just `pop` parameters off the stack (and expect `ret` to work). Suggest you get a regular `proc` working before you tackle recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frank Kotler is right if you insists on having the call parameters on stack then you have 2 options:

1. change your call sequence

   - this is not very good option because of the need of return address labels
2. change your parameters aquisition inside your procedure

   - this is much better way

Option 1:

```
    push adr0
    push x0
    push y0
    push x1
    push y1
    jmp line_recursive
adr0:
```

Option 2:

```
tmp:    dw 0
line_recursive:
    pop eax           ; eax= return address - not shore if you are using 16/32 bit adress so for 16 bits should be only ax
    pop dx            ; dx = y1
    pop cx            ; cx = x1
    pop bx            ; bx = y0
    pop ax            ; ax = x0
    mov [cs:tmp],ax
    push eax          ; restore return adress - not shore if you are using 16/32 bit adress so for 16 bits should be only ax
    mov ax,[cs:tmp]   ; ax = x0

    cmp dx, bx       ; y1==y0
    jne version1
    cmp ax, cx       ; x1==x0
    je  version2

version1:

    mov si,ax
    add si,cx
    mov di,bx
    add di,dx
    shr si, 1         ; si = (x1+x0)/2 = x
    shr di, 1         ; di = (y1+y0)/2 = y

    push ax
    push cx
    push dx
    mov ah,0Ch  ;print pixel.
    mov al,12
    mov cx,si
    mov dx,di
    int 10h
    pop dx
    pop cx
    pop ax

    push ax ; stack for call for (x0,y0, x,y)
    push bx
    push si
    push di
    call line_recursive     ; (x1,y1, x,y)

    push cx ; stack for call for (x1,y1, x,y)
    push dx
    push si
    push di
    call line_recursive     ; (x0,y0, x,y)

version2:
    ret
```

**Do not forget to transform my code to your assembler specifications**

- btw you forgot to mention which one you use, what platform,OS , model ,....

Comment: Did not think it mattered, as my question was mostly about the algorithm itself, rather than its implementation. If I was wrong: 8086 assembly on Win XP 32-bit. We did not use 32-bit registers though.

Comment: call and ret instructions depend on the CPU mode, because the address size is not the same (16/32/64 bit wide) and also if a far call/ret is made then also segment address is pushed/popped to/from the stack. To be entire shore put a breakpoint before call and step the call and see what difference it made on the stack and (e)ss:(e)sp register pair

Comment: Got it now, I understand I should have added info you talk about. I will check the code when I get back to my virtual-machine XP.